# Why can't I set an iterator on a list in a vector?

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

I have a vector of lists defined like this:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> lists;
```

I'm passing it to my function like this:

```
na.add(end, lists[i], end);
```

here's the function I'm passing it to:

```
// Adds values two lists, maintaining three digits per node
void add(std::list<int> &val1, std::list<int> &val2, std::list<int> &end) {
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = val1.rbegin();
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = val2.rbegin();
    int carry = 0;
    int sum;
    while (rit1 != val1.rend()) {
        sum = *rit1 + *rit2 + carry;
        carry = 0;
        if (sum / 1000 == 1) { // Carries values to keep nodes at 3 digits
            carry = 1;
            sum -= 1000;
        }
        end.push_front(sum);
        ++rit1;
        ++rit2;
        }

}
```

The debugger sees the list properly, and sets a iterator for end, but not for list[i]. It works fine when single list is passed, but not a list held in a vector.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: reproducible problem

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class NodeArithmetic {
private:
    int digit;

public:
    // Populates linked list with each node holding 3 digits
    void populateList(int x, std::list<int> &numbers){
    if (x >= 1000 || x <= -1000) {
        populateList(x / 1000, numbers); // Recursive function to grab chunks of 3 digits
    }
    digit = x % 1000;
    numbers.push_back(digit);
}
// Adds values two lists, maintaining three digits per node
void add(std::list<int> &val1, std::list<int> &val2, std::list<int> &end) {
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = val1.rbegin();
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = val2.rbegin();
    int carry = 0;
    int sum;
    while (rit1 != val1.rend()) {
        sum = *rit1 + *rit2 + carry;
        carry = 0;
        if (sum / 1000 == 1) { // Carries values to keep nodes at 3 digits
            carry = 1;
            sum -= 1000;
        }
        end.push_front(sum);
        ++rit1;
        ++rit2;
        }

}


};


int main()
{

std::list<int> end;
std::list<int> nums;
std::list<int> threeDigits;
std::vector<bool> signs;
std::vector<std::list<int>> lists;
std::list<int>::iterator it;
bool flag;
nums.push_back(3453);
nums.push_back(6454);
nums.push_back(-542);
nums.push_back(47842124);
it = nums.begin();
NodeArithmetic na;
while (it != nums.end()) {
    na.populateList(abs(*it), threeDigits);
    lists.push_back(threeDigits);
    threeDigits.clear();
    ++it;
}

for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) { // adds nodes of leading 0's
    for (int j = 0; j < lists.size(); j++) {
        while (lists[j].size() < lists[i].size()) {
            lists[j].push_front(0);
        }
    }
}
while (end.size() < lists[1].size()) {
    end.push_front(0); // nodes of leading 0's to results list
}

na.add(end, lists[0], end);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the way you are passing the list on that particular line. The problem is likely in code you haven't shown us. But side note, `val1` and `val2` should be taken by `const` reference since you don't modify them.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you show here isnt complete in the sense that others cannot reproduce the error you get

Comment: ...btw do you get an error? If yes, what error is it?

Comment: added the full code. It says the list iterator is not decrementable, but debugging it looks like it is never assigned.

edit: and thanks for the tip- I'll change them to const.

Comment: ...ok one step at a time... this is complete, but not minimal. Please remove anything not relevant to the question (especially that huge comment blocks arent the cause of the problem)

Comment: Fair enough. Better?

Comment: @AdamFlammino The example code does not even compile. Did you test this sample?

Comment: @cdhowie sorry- I did, but then I saw some more code that wasn't really needed and accidentally deleted too much.

Comment: (can't edit) I guess that means no, I didn't really test it since I changed after the test. Sorry for all the issues- first time I've actually asked a question here. Usually my problems are already solved by other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually quite simple: inside of `add()` you keep adding items to the front of `val1` (via `end`) and so the `while` loop never terminates, and eventually `val2` runs out of items.

Consider:

- In `na.add(end, lists[0], end)` you are passing the first and third arguments by reference, so within `add()` it is true that `&val1 == &end` -- that is, both arguments refer to the same list.
- Your loop tries to loop from the end of `val1` to the beginning of `val1`.
- But each iteration, you invoke `end.push_front(sum)` which prepends an item to the front of `end` (which is the same list as `val1`).
- Therefore, the loop will never terminate because you keep adding items to the list you are enumerating.  `rit1` will never be equal to `val1.rend()`. (So even if the program did not crash right away, it would run until it exhausted available memory and *then* it would crash.)
- Additionally, since there is no test to see if `rit2` is equal to `val2.end()`, you run out of items in the list referred to by `val2`, hence your "iterator not decrementable" error.  As soon as `rit2 == val2.rend()`, the expressions `*rit2` and `++rit2` invoke undefined behavior.

Possible solutions:

- Change your `while` condition to additionally test if `rit2 != val2.rend()`.
- Pass a different list as the third argument to `add()` (though it would be wise to additionally test that `val1.size() == val2.size()` if this is a precondition of `add()`).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I hadn't thought that through. It makes sense now that it worked before when I was only adding two lists since that meant end and val1 were different lists.